# DateTimeFormatter 2 digit hour and minute (not manual with string concat)

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for time management in my app.
I want to get the hour and minute from a DateTime with 2 digits.

Example:

if the hour is 8 and the minutes 5
I want to get **08:05**

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPatter("H:m");
dt.toString(dtf);
```

I know that I can achieve this with manual string concat, but I don't want it.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried "HH:mm" for pattern? it will print Hours and minutes using 2 digits for each (in your case 08:05)

Comment: What will that do? (Please from your answer as an answer.)

Comment: Yeah that worked, I feel stupid for not trying that, it's obvious!  thanx